# Increment in fetch array while loop

Tags: php, algorithm, grouping

I have trouble to increment correctly a variable in a while loop where I fetch data from my database.

This is the code:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //January
    if ($row['month'] ==1){
        if ($row['day_range'] == '01-07') {
            $val1_1 = $row['duration'];
            $int1_1 = $row['intensity'];
        }
        elseif ($row['day_range'] == '08-14') {
            $val1_2 = $row['duration'];
            $int1_2 = $row['intensity'];
        }
        elseif ($row['day_range'] == '15-21') {
            $val1_3 = $row['duration'];
            $int1_3 = $row['intensity'];
        }
        elseif ($row['day_range'] == '22-end') {
            $val1_4 = $row['duration'];
            $int1_4 = $row['intensity'];
        }
        //Avg intensity
        $int1 = ($int1_1 + $int1_2 + $int1_3 + $int1_4)/4;
    }
}
```

So I have this code for every month.
The problem here is that sometimes **I don't have 4 values**, so at the end when I calculate the AVG it is sometimes wrong because it always divides it by **4**

**What I've done :**

I had the idea of incrementing a variable $i each time I have a value, like this

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //January
    if ($row['month'] ==1) {
        if ($row['day_range'] == '01-07') {
            $val1_1 = $row['duration'];
            $int1_1 = $row['intensity'];
            $i++;
        }
        elseif ($row['day_range'] == '08-14') {
            $val1_2 = $row['duration'];
            $int1_2 = $row['intensity'];
            $i++;
        }
        elseif ($row['day_range'] == '15-21') {
            $val1_3 = $row['duration'];
            $int1_3 = $row['intensity'];
            $i++;
        }
        elseif ($row['day_range'] == '22-end') {
            $val1_4 = $row['duration'];
            $int1_4 = $row['intensity'];
            $i++;
        }
        //Avg intensity
        $int1 = ($int1_1 + $int1_2 + $int1_3 + $int1_4)/$i;
    }
    $i = 0;
    //code for next month
}
```

But it doesn't work, I've echoed it and `$i` stays at 1.
I think it is because it fetch row by row so it never goes through all incrementations to reach the value desired.

How can I do that please?

Comment: Try by removing `$i=0` from last.

Comment: Do you add `$row['intensity']` in all cases?  Why not add to an array `$ints[] = $row['intensity']`, and then after to get the average do `array_sum($ints)/count($ints)`?

Comment: If `$row` is a single row, it'll only run `$i++` once.

Comment: It's normal, you need to pass 4 time in your while loop to get the result no?

Comment: It looks to me as if you'll only enter one of those if/elseif statements per row fetch, so only ever have one intensity value per row.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @prit.patel I tried, it didn't work, it kept the incrementations of other months

Comment: @Progrock Yes I do. Because I don't want the average of all months, I need it for each months.

Comment: Perhaps explain your problem better, I'm just reading redundant code above.

Comment: @rn605435 I post an anwser that should give you want you want with an other method and less code if you want to try it :) I'm aware of your question if something don't work !

Comment: @MickaelLeger I've seen it, thanks to your comments I was able to use it easily. Thank you for your help

Comment: This question is incomplete/unclear because there is no [mcve]. Please [edit] this question to include realistic sample data and your exact desired result from that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Here is an array to get the data of EACH month
$month = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // This way, you will have $month[1] for January, $month[2] for February, etc.
    $month[$row['month']][] = array(
        "duration" => $row['duration'],
        "intensity" => $row['intensity'];
    );
}

// Now you get all the data, you can calculate the Avg intensity for each month
foreach ($month as $month_number => $data) {
    $moy = count($month[$month_number]); // Will be 4 if you have 4 period, 3 if only 3, etc.
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $sum += $value['intensity'];
    }

    $month[$month_number]['avg_intensity'] = $sum / $moy;
}
```

With this method you should get an array with all the data you want that look like this :

```
$month = array(
    // January
    1 => array(
        0 => array(
            'duration' => ...,
            'intensity' => ...
        ),
        1 => array(
            'duration' => ...,
            'intensity' => ...
        ),
        ...
        'avg_intensity' => /* moy of all intensity of the month */
    ),
    // February
    2 => array(
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

Hope it helps you !

**EDIT :**

As suggested if the comment by Nigel Ren, you can replace

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $sum += $value['intensity'];
}
```

By

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($data, "intensity"));
```

Comment: Written something similar to this - as it saves multiples of code for each month.

Comment: I edited my anwser you were right about `count($month_number)`n thanks ! And about `array_sum` are you sure? Because the array has two value (duration and intensity) foreach period. Since I can test it myself I prefer the foreach to be sure but I'm sure a php array function is usable !

Comment: If you have multiple columns, then use `array_column()` to pick out the one your after.

Comment: @MickaelLeger There is an issue though, let's say I want the value of the first range of January I will use $month[0][0]['duration'], right? But if I don't have data for this particular range and data for the others, than [0]['duration'] might be the 2nd, 3rd or 4th range duration value instead of null

Comment: Maybe you can do `$month[$row['month']][$row['day_range']] = array(...)` in the while loop, this way you will have the period + the data? This way you can check if the period exist + get the data according to the period you want. Is it clear or should I edit my question?

Comment: It is clear but I don't know how to proceed with the checking part

Comment: Since you have 4 period, you can try somehting like `if(isset($month[/* the month number */][/* your period */])) { //Then you check $month[/* the month number */][/* your period */]['duration'] OR ...['intensity'] }`

Answer (score 0):

Please try like

```
 $int1_1 += $row['intensity'];
```

way. 
That means

```
  $i = 0;
$int1_1 = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            //January
            if($row['month'] ==1){
                if($row['day_range'] == '01-07'){
                    $val1_1 = $row['duration'];
                    $int1_1 += $row['intensity'];
                    $i++;
                }
                elseif($row['day_range'] == '08-14'){
                    $val1_2 = $row['duration'];
                    $int1_1 +=  $row['intensity'];
                    $i++;
                }
                elseif($row['day_range'] == '15-21'){
                    $val1_3 = $row['duration'];
                    $int1_1 +=  = $row['intensity'];
                    $i++;
                }
                elseif($row['day_range'] == '22-end'){
                    $val1_4 = $row['duration'];
                    $int1_1 +=  $row['intensity'];
                    $i++;
                }
                //Avg intensity
                $int1 = $int1_1/$i;
            }
            $i=0;
            //code for next month

}
```